# Accordion item doesn't show up the way it should

Tags: c#

I am writing a silverlight page, in my application and I got a weird problem.

So, in my page, I got three accordion item : 2 of them are static, 1 is dynamic.

I bind dataSource for each accordion item, and so, the last one dataSource depends on the two firsts.

```
        foreach (CadreEmp item in CadreEmpSource.DataView)
        {

            Catproc isInCat = CatprocSource.DataView.OfType<Catproc>().Where(ores => ores.IdCat == item.IdCat).FirstOrDefault();
            Filproc isInFil = FilprocSource.DataView.OfType<Filproc>().Where(ores => ores.IdFil == item.IdFil).FirstOrDefault();
            if (isInCat != null && isInFil != null)
            {
                CadreEmpUI caUi = new CadreEmpUI();
                caUi.IdCadreEmp = item.IdCadreEmp;
                caUi.IdCat = item.IdCat;
                caUi.IdFil = item.IdFil;
                caUi.LibCadreEmp = item.LibCadreEmp;
                caUi.IsSelect = item.IsSelect;
                lstCadreEmp.Add(caUi);
                CadreEmpProc caP = CadreEmpProcSource.DataView.OfType<CadreEmpProc>().Where(ores => ores.IdCadreEmp == caUi.IdCadreEmp).FirstOrDefault();
                if (caP != null)
                {
                    caUi.IsSelect = true;
                }

            }
        }

        dgCadreEmp.ItemsSource = null;
        dgCadreEmp.ItemsSource = lstCadreEmp;
```

So, basically, it works fine, except some times, when tihs is not displays correctly in the accordion, like this :

[image: accordion bugging]
[image: accordion non bugging]

We see in the first image, there is no bottom border. Because there is another line above.

And when I close and open the accordion(without touching the datasource, I got the second image, that is display correctly.

I don't understant, I tried close and open it programatically after I set the item source

```
        aiCadreEmp.IsSelected = false;
        aiCadreEmp.IsSelected = true;
```

But nothing. Tried update the layout, nothing.

i do not understant at all. Thank you.

The xaml code :

```
      <layout:Accordion Width="Auto"         
                        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                        Grid.Column="4"
                        Grid.RowSpan="2"
                        x:Name="accCadreEmp"
                        SelectionMode="ZeroOrOne"
                        ExpandDirection="Down"
                        Grid.Row="0">
             <layout:AccordionItem 
                     x:Name="aiCadreEmp">
                     <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                          <sdk:DataGrid x:Name="dgCadreEmp"                                                                       
MaxWidth="1200"
AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
                         <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                              <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Libellé"
                                                      IsReadOnly="True"
                                                      Binding="{Binding LibCadreEmp}" />
                              </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                         </sdk:DataGrid>
                      </StackPanel>
               </layout:AccordionItem>
      </layout:Accordion>
```

Comment: Why are you have DataGrid in StackPanel?

Comment: @ad1Dima Well, it was in case I need to add another item in this block(like buttons...). But you made a point. Since I remove the stackPanel, it update well. How can this stackpanel, make bugging the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StackPanel provides infinity height its children, sometimes it causes strange side effects, especially when it needs to dynamically resize it. I guess, in that case accordion also provides infinity height to its children, so we have not well known behavior.

If you just need 2 or 3 rows, use Grid instead.

Comment: Thank you. I never though that it could be the stack panel that was made bugging my application.

Comment: I thought, DataGrid also must provide infinity height to its children. In case it has also infinity parent (like StackPanel, ScrollViewer or Canvas) it mas measure itself by content. May be there is bug in this step.